# Make Python 3 default on Mac OS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I would like to ask if it is possible to make Python 3 a default interpreter on Mac OS 10 when typing python right away from the terminal? If so, can somebody help how to do it? I'm avoiding switching between the environments.

Cheers

Comment: You need to change it as the default virtual environment:
https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Comment: @Chrispresso true but there is no answer to that post, anyways thanks.

Comment: The answer has a big check-mark next to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Method 1:**

In `~/.bash_profile`, set an alias for your `python3`

```
alias python='python3'
```

**Method 2(I use this way to keep multiple python versions):**

Install python3(the virtualenv python3 on my machine is env-3.5) by `virtualenv`, in `~/.bash_profile` activate certain virtual environment:

```
source /Users/username/.virtualenvs/env-3.5/bin/activate
```

I suggest use a virtual environment, it will affect your system even packages messed up.

## update:

Did research on anaconda which data_garden commented. Here I post how I installed it:

- Go to page https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos find the package meet your system requirement, for me it's MacOS
- Add to system PATH `export PATH=$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` into `.bash_profile`
- Search available python versions `conda search "^python$"`
- Create env: `conda  create -n env-3.6.5 python=3.6.5`  , env-3.6.5 is the name of the new created env
- Activate env: `source activate env-3.6.5`, add it into `.bash_profile`

Done!

You can run `conda env list` to display all virtual environments you have created.

[image]

Comment: and, if chosing a virtual environment approach, I suggest you try installing `anaconda` and creating envs for your python versions, which are a bit more intuitive than `virtualenv`. for conda you would just type `source activate py35` and that's it.

Comment: @data_gardens can you demonstrate this by an example?

Comment: @data_garden haven't tried it yet, it would be appreciated if you can post an instruction here!

Comment: @data_garden just installed anaconda, pretty cool!

Comment: @gumedean see my update if you're insterested in `anaconda`

Comment: @data_garden thanks a lot, this was helpful.

Comment: you're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by changing alias, typing in something like `$ alias python=python3` in the terminal.
If you want the change to persist open `~/.bash_profile` using nano and then add alias `python=python3`. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to close.
Then type `$ source ~./bash_profile` in the terminal.